# Server's JSON response might be invalid

Tags: java, android, json, loopj

I get stuck for this, I don't understand where the problem from.
The API was tested Success with Postman, but failure on my app.

My code is:

```
public void invokeWS(RequestParams params) {
    // Show Progress Dialog
    prgDialog.show();
    // Make RESTful webservice call using AsyncHttpClient object
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post("http://openetizen.com/api/v1/sessions", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            // Hide Progress Dialog
            prgDialog.hide();
            try {
                // JSON Object
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(responseBody));
                Log.v("Response", String.valueOf(responseBody));
                // When the JSON response has status boolean value assigned with true
                if (obj.getBoolean("status")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selamat datang!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Navigate to Home screen
                    navigatetoMainActivity();
                }
                // Else display error message
                else {
                    errorMsg.setText(obj.getString("error_msg"));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("error_msg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("ERROR", "Response");


            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Message obtainMessage(int responseMessageId, Object responseMessageData) {
            return super.obtainMessage(responseMessageId, responseMessageData);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getTag() {
            return super.getTag();
        }

        @Override
        public void setTag(Object TAG) {
            super.setTag(TAG);
        }

        @Override
        public URI getRequestURI() {
            return super.getRequestURI();
        }

        @Override
        public void setRequestURI(URI requestURI) {
            super.setRequestURI(requestURI);
        }

        @Override
        public Header[] getRequestHeaders() {
            return super.getRequestHeaders();
        }

        @Override
        public void setRequestHeaders(Header[] requestHeaders) {
            super.setRequestHeaders(requestHeaders);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
            return super.getUseSynchronousMode();
        }

        @Override
        public void setUseSynchronousMode(boolean sync) {
            super.setUseSynchronousMode(sync);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getUsePoolThread() {
            return super.getUsePoolThread();
        }

        @Override
        public void setUsePoolThread(boolean pool) {
            super.setUsePoolThread(pool);
        }

        @Override
        public String getCharset() {
            return super.getCharset();
        }

        @Override
        public void setCharset(String charset) {
            super.setCharset(charset);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(long bytesWritten, long totalSize) {
            super.onProgress(bytesWritten, totalSize);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            super.onFinish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreProcessResponse(ResponseHandlerInterface instance, HttpResponse response) {
            super.onPreProcessResponse(instance, response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostProcessResponse(ResponseHandlerInterface instance, HttpResponse response) {
            super.onPostProcessResponse(instance, response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
            super.onRetry(retryNo);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            super.onCancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserException(Throwable error) {
            super.onUserException(error);
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleMessage(Message message) {
            super.handleMessage(message);
        }

        @Override
        protected void sendMessage(Message msg) {
            super.sendMessage(msg);
        }

        @Override
        protected void postRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
            super.postRunnable(runnable);
        }

        @Override
        public void sendResponseMessage(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
            super.sendResponseMessage(response);
        }

        @Override
        protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            return super.clone();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return super.equals(o);
        }

        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            super.finalize();
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return super.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            // Hide Progress Dialog
            prgDialog.hide();
            // When Http response code is '404'
            if (statusCode == 404) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // When Http response code is '500'
            else if (statusCode == 500) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // When Http response code other than 404, 500
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And error occurs here:

```
catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("ERROR", "Response");


            }
```

[API Tested Success on Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i055Y.png)

[Tested failure on Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtbyC.png)

What Should I do to fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I got tutorial from here http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-how-to-call-restful-webservice-in-android-part-3/

Comment: Did you try to debug it yet?

Comment: already debug :  Log.e("ERROR", "Response"); | on console E/ERROR: Response

Comment: So you got it at line `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(responseBody));`

Comment: @ThanhDuyNgo yes now error occurs here http://prntscr.com/9b9xuc

Comment: Because you try to parse `byte[ ]` to `String`.. You should use another solution for this. Ex: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-byte-array-to-string-in-java/ 
Or can search any different solutions for this.

Comment: Paste your json  response in http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ site and verify the JSON.

Comment: try `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new  String(responseBody));` If it still get error, your returned json may be wrong format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This and let me know the result

```
try 
{
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
     if (obj.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("success") {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selamat datang!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     navigatetoMainActivity();
}
else {
    errorMsg.setText(obj.getString("error_msg"));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("error_msg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```